# Data flow image processing software like simulink

Tags: image-processing, data-visualization

Is there any data flow image processing software like [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink)?

I want a software like Simulink in which we can simply drag and drop tools without any coding. when you want to do a sequence of tasks on images, you do it simply by using ready to use components and tools without any coding in the background.( i.e data visualization and data-flow based).

Simulink is a good option but it has low performance. I want a program to be fast,rich(do many of image processing tasks) and also preferably open source and windows-based.

Comment: Welcome to the SoftWrecks, abdolah! Could you please [edit] your question and include a link to *Simulink* for reference? Congrats besides that you didn't tap into the usual ["something alike" trap](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185), but explicitely named some of your requirements. The more precise you've put your requirements, the better fit answers you should expect – so if there's anything more, be welcome to include it. Good luck so far!